# type() input, print based on data type()

Tags: python, python-2.7, types

Write a function data_type which takes an argument and prints out the data type of that argument. So if we give a string as input it will say that our input is a string and same if we give an integer or a float.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong if anyone could give me some explanation, I would appreciate it so much! Hope I was clear with the question.

```
def data_type(x,y):
    for i in x,y:
        if i == type(str):
            print "str"
        elif i == type(int):
            print "int"
        else:
            if i == type(float):
                print "float"

data_type(1,"string")
```

Comment: You d it the opposite way, it should be `type(i) == int`, not `i == type(int)`...

Comment: The function should take *one*  argument. Start your Python and enter `type(0)`, `type([])`, and `type("hello")`. Observe the results. (You can't enumerate all the potentially existing types, so a bunch of conditionals won't do much good.)

Comment: It sounds like you just want the function `type`...

Comment: Thanks to you guys, now I understand where my mistake is, a bit stupid but I have started recently in programming....

Comment: @molbdnilo Would you mind demonstrating your method, if you have time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are thinking too colloquially. `i == type(str)` reads vaguely like "i is of type string" but it does not actually mean that.

You can find out what `type(str)` is by entering it into your interpreter. It will tell you that `str` is of type `type`, which makes sense because `str` is a type.

So for example, `"hello" == type(str)` is the same thing as `"hello" == type`. This makes no sense -- the string "hello" is clearly not the same thing as the concept of `type`, so it evaluates to `False`.

What you actually want to ask is whether the `type` of "hello" is the same thing as the type `str`. Which you can check as follows: `type(i) == str`. Similar adjustments for the rest of your code would make it work.

Comment: Thank you for your effort sir!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler implementation of your function:

```
def print_types(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(type(arg).__name__)
```

Some notes on this:

the `*args` syntax allows the function to take many positional arguments, they will be "packed" into `args` (which will be available to the function as a tuple).  `type(x)` will return the type of `x`, which has a `__name__` attribute.

Note that for "old style" classes (in python2, those which do not inherit from `object`), this is slightly incorrect and you'll need to adjust for that:

```
>>> class C: pass
... 
>>> type(C())
<type 'instance'>
>>> type(C()).__name__
# Not what we want
'instance'
```

If you also want to handle old-style objects:

```
def print_types(*args):
    for arg in args:
        try:
            print(arg.__class__.__name__)
        except AttributeError:
            print(type(arg).__name__)
```

A quick demonstration

```
>>> class C: pass
... 
>>> class D(object): pass
... 
>>> print_types(C, C(), D, D(), 'foo', 2)
classobj
C
type
D
str
int
```

In python3 where there's no concept of an "old style class" you'll get the following:

```
>>> print_types(C, C(), D, D(), 'foo', 2)
type
C
type
D
str
int
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort, I understood your concept, however right now I am not allowed to use classes since I haven't still covered them in my university lectures, I will be dealing with them after 1 month. Definitely this will be helpful in the future!